# DnD 3.5 Pacts with Demons question

Tags: dnd-3.5e, warlock

Was wondering. Is it possible to "buy" your pact from a demon to not go to abyss. If yes...what would  be the price? and what are the consequences of that? Losing power or you can keep it? did any handbook said about it?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. This question's been closed not because the site thinks it's a *bad* question but, instead, because, as written, the question is about a unique campaign with house rules the site can't know, fix, or interpret. That is, for example, if the campaign has warlocks bargaining away their souls for power (which it sounds like they do), then that's different from, "The exact nature of a warlock’s origin is up to the player to decide" (*CAr* 6), so the site just can't help. Thank you for participating, though.

Answer (score 3):

**Ask your GM.** This is entirely dependant on the setting, the specificities of the pact, and the personality of the demon in question.